# Gmail API access on desktop + service bus endpoint, share token?

Tags: oauth, gmail, gmail-api, google-authentication

I have a desktop and service bus that works in unison.

Basically I want to set it up so that the desktop app allows the user to authorise the desktop and service bus access to read and create emails on behalf of the user.

Firstly if I pass the access token to the server to save, I read that it's short lived, how would I ensure the server can always access the gmail apis if the access token ends up expiring?

On the desktop its interactive for the gmail api libraries to spawn a new web page, but on the service bus endpoint, it can't exactly call one of the authorize methods the gmail .net app provides and be able to have the user re-authorise it.

So what's the best approach to keep this as seamless as possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: save the refresh token a refresh token can then be used to get a new access token at anytime.

Comment: @DaImTo For some reason if I use the Gmail .NET MVC libraries to authenticate, there's no refresh token passed back, but with the client side libraries they do, I'm guessing the libraries are limiting?

Comment: If you are using Googles official client lib then it returns a refresh token.  I am not familiar with "Gmail .NET MVC libraries"

Comment: @DaImTo sorry I am referring to the google official client lib, but I was referring more specifically to this code example:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications

versus this one:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#installed_applications

They both have their own AuthorizeAsync methods in two different classes, where the installed app returns the refresh token, and the MVC example doesn't seem to.

Comment: I think you need to post some code then because the refreshtoken is returned.

Comment: @DaImTo updated my post, sorry

Comment: @DaImTo never mind I see the refresh token inside the usercredential.token object. So if the client does the authorization etc and sends the access token and refresh token for that user to the service, how does that service use the google .net libraries to reconstruct the credential object? Because the credential object appears to need a flow object of some sort?

Comment: again you need to post some code.  I will assume you are using filedatastore, that is probably where its being stored.

Comment: @DaImTo The code is identical to the two links I linked you to, I haven't made any modifications to it, so they're just vanilla snippets, yes it's using the default FileDataStore, I've cracked open that file which is pretty much just json token payload object.

Comment: @DaImTo I mean I can easily extract the accessToken and refreshToken and send it to the server, but once the server has it, I'm not exactly sure how I construct a UserCredential object back from those two values, because the way the UserCredential object is obtained, at least via the code sample google provided is through the AuthorizationCodeMvcApp.AuthroizeAsync method.

Comment: I am sorry with out you posting code showing how you are using AuthorizationCodeMvcApp.AuthroizeAsync  I don't think anyone can help you.

Comment: @DaImTo sorry for the delayed reply, been experimenting with some stuff, and have asserted some changes, and I've raised another question sort of linked to this, located here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286164/google-auth-api-application-type-how-important-is-it