# Google AUTH API Application Type, how important is it?

Tags: google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, gmail-api, google-authentication

I've been doing a lot tinkering around with the authentication stuff using the .NET libraries provided by Google.

We have both a desktop and web-app side, and what we want to achieve is to authenticate ONCE, either on the desktop or the web side, and store the refresh token, and reuse it both on the web side and the desktop side.

So the situation is like so, on the desktop side, when there's no saved existing AccessToken's and RefreshToken's, we will ask the user to authenticate via this code:

```
            using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets_desktop.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly, GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose },
                "someemail@gmail.com", CancellationToken.None);
        }
```

In this case the Client ID and Secret is of an Application type Installed Application.

On the web-application side, if there's also no refresh token yet then I'm using DotNetOpenAuth to trigger the authentication, here's the code snippet:

```
   const string clientID = "someclientid";
    const string clientSecret = "somesecret";
    const string redirectUri = "http://localhost/Home/oauth2callback";
    AuthorizationServerDescription server = new AuthorizationServerDescription
    {
        AuthorizationEndpoint = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth"),
        TokenEndpoint = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"),
        ProtocolVersion = ProtocolVersion.V20
    };

    public ActionResult AuthenticateMe()
    {
        List<string> scope = new List<string> 
        { 
            GmailService.Scope.GmailCompose,
            GmailService.Scope.GmailReadonly,
            GmailService.Scope.GmailModify
        };

        WebServerClient consumer = new WebServerClient(server, clientID, clientSecret);

        // Here redirect to authorization site occurs
        OutgoingWebResponse response = consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(
            scope, new Uri(redirectUri));
        response.Headers["Location"] += "&access_type=offline&approval_prompt=force";
        return response.AsActionResult();

    }

    public void oauth2callback()
    {
        WebServerClient consumer = new WebServerClient(server, clientID, clientSecret);
        consumer.ClientCredentialApplicator =
            ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter(clientSecret);
        IAuthorizationState grantedAccess = consumer.ProcessUserAuthorization(null);

        string accessToken = grantedAccess.AccessToken;

    }
```

Here is where I want to confirm my suspicions.

When there is a RefreshToken that exists, we use the following code snippet to call the Gmail API's

```
    UserCredential uc = new UserCredential(flow, "someemail@gmail.com", new TokenResponse()
        {
            AccessToken = "lastaccesstoken",
            TokenType = "Bearer",
            RefreshToken = "supersecretrefreshtoken"
        });
    var refreshState = await uc.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);


    var svc = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = uc,
        ApplicationName = "Gmail Test",
    });
```

Here's the thing I noticed is that, for me to be able to use the refresh token to refresh from either the desktop or the web side, the refresh token needs to be generated through the same client ID/secret combination. I've tested it and it seems like it's fine if we use Installed application as the application type for the Client ID for both the desktop and the web, but my question I guess is, these application type's for the client IDs, do they matter so much?

Am I doing anything wrong to do it this way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This site really isn't for code review.  Your code is different then how I normally do it but if it works I think its fine.  You are correct as long as the client id, secret, and refreshtoken match you can use it on both web and native applications.  why they are different is a very good question.